# Using Git Bash on Windows, how do I checkout/rename a branch that begins with a Unicode character?

Tags: bash, git, unicode, git-bash

I use git bash for git related activities on windows.

I created a branch, did some changes and committed. When I tried to push, it gives me:

error `"refpath does not exist"`.

I then checkout to other branch and retried to checkout to my branch but it says

error: pathspec `'feature/my-branch'` did not match any file(s) known to git.

on running git branch, it lists my branch name as-

```
<U+0085><U+0085><U+0085><U+0086>feature/my-branch
```

I tried renaming this branch but that also didn't work.

```
git branch -m  '<U+0085><U+0085><U+0085><U+0086>feature/my-branch' feature/new-branch
```

what is the reason behind this and what could be the possible solution?

Comment: If you don't need to keep the associated reflog, maybe just create a new branch from the badly named one (which you can then delete)? About the reasons behind such an odd name, maybe a (dirty) copy-pasted string upon creation?

Comment: @romain I'm unable to even checkout to that badly named branch. If that was possible, I would have created a new branch from that.

Comment: try executing this command : ```git checkout $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | sed "s/^.*\([\\/]\)/\1/" | sed 's/[^/]*$/\u0085\u0085\u0085\u0086feature\/my-branch/')```

Comment: Maybe easier to go for a bit of spellunking in `.git/refs/heads` to check for the faulty branch and extract whatever hash it points to (if you can).

Comment: A workaround is to create a new branch. Use `git for-each-ref refs/heads` to list all branches and corresponding commits. Create a new branch from the right commit.

Comment: @Shachar297 It would be helpful to explain what your command does.

Comment: @skomisa common usage of ```git rev-parse``` is to print the SHA1 hashes given a revision specifier, while the ```sed``` searches a branch name by regex.

Comment: Surely a name like that will be one you'll want to fix permanently for all platforms? It's probably easier to check it out on a  Linux system, fix and commit, then return to Windows if you can't yet graduate permanently to Linux or Mac. There are many "live CD" distros you can boot from a USB stick without messing with the currently installed OS on your hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unwanted unicode chracters are converted to sequences such as `<U+0085>` or `<U+0086>` *when they are printed on your terminal*.

`faulty=$(git branch | grep -a feature/my-branch)` should hold the "correct" value for that branch name, so this should work:

```
# The '-a' option to grep is there to skip grep's auto detection of binary content
# it could kick in if there was a '\x00' byte in the input
#
# Your specific issue (with <U+0085> characters) shouldn't trigger it, I'm just
# mentioning that option for a more general scope
faulty=$(git branch | grep -a feature/my-branch)

# to avoid shenanigans with leading spaces and a possible '*' in the output:
faulty=$(git branch --format="%(refname:short)" | grep -a feature/my-branch)

git branch -m "$faulty" feature/my-branch
```

---

Otherwise:

- bash itself should know

use the `$'...'` syntax to have a string with the escape sequences interpreted:

```
git branch -m $'\u0085\u0085\u0085\u0086feature/my-branch' feature/my-branch
```

- `printf` knows about `\uXXXX` sequences

you can try to run :

```
faulty=$(printf "\u0085\u0085\u0085\u0086feature/my-branch")
# you can check if 'echo "$faulty"' gives you the same output as 'git branch'

git branch -m "$faulty" feature/my-branch
```